# Excel VBA Code - OELDB Connection

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get data from one excel file to another with the code below, and when it goes through the GetData macro it automatically exits out after the rsData.Open command, so it never drops off the data from the closed workbook into the open workbook.

```
Public Sub GetData(SourceFile As Variant, SourceSheet As String, _
                   SourceRange As String, TargetRange As Range, _
                   Header As Boolean, UseHeaderRow As Boolean)

    Dim rsCon As Object
    Dim rsData As Object
    Dim szConnect As String
    Dim szSQL As String
    Dim lCount As Long

    ' Create the connection string.
    If Header = False Then
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No"";"
        Else
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"";"
        End If
    Else
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"
        Else
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"";"
        End If
    End If

    If SourceSheet = "" Then
        ' workbook level name
        szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & SourceRange$ & ";"
    Else
        ' worksheet level name or range
        szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "];"
    End If

    On Error GoTo SomethingWrong

    Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    rsCon.Open szConnect
    rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1

    ' Check to make sure we received data and copy the data
    If Not rsData.EOF Then

        If Header = False Then
            TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox "No records returned from : " & SourceFile, vbCritical
    End If

    ' Clean up our Recordset object.
    rsData.Close
    Set rsData = Nothing
    rsCon.Close
    Set rsCon = Nothing
    Exit Sub

SomethingWrong:
    MsgBox "The file name, Sheet name or Range is invalid of : " & SourceFile, _
                 vbExclamation, "Error"
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub

Sub Update_DW_BaseCase()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationSemiautomatic
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next

    folder = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
    dw_file_name = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    model = Dir(folder & "*Base Case.xls*")

    irow = 2
    irow_descriptives = 2
    error_string = ""

    Do While Len(model) > 0

        GetData model, "Data Dump", "A7:EL85", Sheets("DATA").Range("A" & irow), False, False
        irow = Sheets("DATA").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row + 1

        GetData model, "Data Dump", "B3:AE3", Sheets("Descriptives").Range("A" & _
                                               irow_descriptives), False, False
        irow_descriptives = irow_descriptives + 1

        model = Dir

    Loop

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationSemiautomatic
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Try adding `Msgbox Err.Description` in your error handler to see what the actual error is.

Comment: Or, alternatively, remove your `On Error GoTo SomethingWrong` line so VBA can tell you what's happening.

Comment: Tools>>Options>>Break on All Errors will work best for finding the erroneous line.